# Unable to select data from oracle even if hibernate query is running

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am hitting below URL:

```
 http://localhost:8080/bot1/deal/index/123
```

I have database table with data as:

---

[DB data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZjT3.png)

---

### My Directory structure:

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euwwu.png)

---

### I am getting below exception and it is printing size of the list as zero for sopln statement is DealDaoImpl because no data present in query:

> Hibernate: select this_.OPTY_NUMBER as OPTY_NUMBER1_0_0_,
>   this_.PROJECT_NAME as PROJECT_NAME2_0_0_ from CQ_CCW_ALL_DEAL this_ 0
>   Hibernate: select this_.OPTY_NUMBER as OPTY_NUMBER1_0_0_,
>   this_.PROJECT_NAME as PROJECT_NAME2_0_0_ from CQ_CCW_ALL_DEAL this_
>   Jun 25, 2017 10:39:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [webmvc-dispatcher] in
>   context with path [/bot1] threw exception [Request processing failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0,
>   Size: 0] with root cause java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   0, Size: 0    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.bot1.serviceImpl.DealServiceImpl.getDealDetails(DealServiceImpl.java:21)
>     at com.bot1.controller.BotController.getDeal(BotController.java:34)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

---

### This is my code:

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>bot1</display-name>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>ApplicationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>webmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

---

### webmvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

---

### applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bot1" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
        <property name="username" value="system" />
        <property name="password" value="tiger" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.bot1.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop> -->
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">test</prop> -->
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

---

### BotController.java

```
package com.bot1.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.bot1.model.Deal;
import com.bot1.service.DealService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("deal")
public class BotController {
@Autowired
private DealService dealService;

@RequestMapping(value="/index/{dealId}",method=RequestMethod.GET)   
private String getDeal(@ModelAttribute("deal1") Deal deal,@PathVariable String dealId) {

    deal= dealService.getDealDetails(dealId);
    System.out.println(deal.getDeal_id());
    System.out.println(deal.getDeal_name());    
    return null;

}
}
```

---

### DealService.java

```
package com.bot1.service;
import com.bot1.model.Deal;

public interface DealService {
     public Deal getDealDetails(String dealId); 
}
```

---

### DealServiceImpl.java

```
package com.bot1.serviceImpl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.bot1.dao.DealDao;
import com.bot1.model.Deal;
import com.bot1.service.DealService;

@Service
public class DealServiceImpl implements DealService {

    @Autowired
    private DealDao dealdao;

    public Deal getDealDetails(String dealId) {
        List<Deal> deals=dealdao.getDeal(dealId);
        return deals.get(0);
    }
}
```

---

### DealDao.java

```
package com.bot1.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.bot1.model.Deal;

public interface DealDao {

      public List<Deal> getDeal(String dealId);
}
```

---

### DealDaoImpl.java

```
  package com.bot1.daoImpl;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
    import com.bot1.dao.DealDao;
    import com.bot1.model.Deal;

    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class DealDaoImpl implements DealDao{

        @Autowired
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<Deal> getDeal(String dealId) {


System.out.println(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Deal.class).list().size());
            return (List<Deal>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Deal.class).list();

        }
    }
```

---

### Deal.java

```
package com.bot1.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CQ_CCW_ALL_DEAL")
public class Deal {

    @Id
    @Column(name="OPTY_NUMBER")
    private String deal_id;

    @Column(name="PROJECT_NAME")
    private String deal_name;

    public String getDeal_id() {
        return deal_id;
    }
    public void setDeal_id(String deal_id) {
        this.deal_id = deal_id;
    }
    public String getDeal_name() {
        return deal_name;
    }
    public void setDeal_name(String deal_name) {
        this.deal_name = deal_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help to find where I am going wrong.

Comment: There was very small error. from applicationContext.xml -  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />   , 1521:XE is replaced with 1521/XE and issue got solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` Exception.
May be due to `public Deal getDealDetails(String dealId) {..deals.get(0)..}` is returning `null`.

This is may occur when you are fetching a deal based on `dealId` which does not exists in DB.

Use `dealId` as 123 or 325.

Comment: You can check DealDaoImpl.java, size I am getting it as 0 even if query is shown on console and since my tables has entries it should return 1. I tried both 123 and 325 , I am getting same exception, public Deal getDealDetails(String dealId) {..deals.get(0)..} will return null only because I am not getting rows and that is only my question, why I am not getting rows

Comment: I can't see any hibernate mapping `one-to-one` etc used to fetched `List<Deal> deals=dealdao.getDeal(dealId);` in DealDaoImpl.java. You need to add hibernate mappings as well.

Comment: why do I need mapping? there is only one table cq_ccw_all_deal in my Backend, why will I add mapping ?

Comment: Mapping is not needed here

Answer (score 0):

There was very small error. from applicationContext.xml -  , 1521:XE is replaced with 1521/XE and issue got solved.